# Mutex on pointers to a shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I am new to thread programming. I know that mutexes are used to protect access to shared data in a multi-threaded program.

Suppose I have one thread with variable ***a*** and a second one with the pointer variable ***p*** that holds the address of ***a***. Is the code safe if, in the second thread, I lock a mutex before I modify the value of ***a*** using the pointer variable? From my understanding it is safe.

Can you confirm? And also can you provide the reason why it is true or why it is not true?

I am working with c and pthreads.

Comment: 1: Does the lifetime of **a** extend to include every access of **p**? 2: Is every access of **a**, though any other pointer, or directly in the thread it is local to, protected by the same mutex?

Comment: Yes to both questions. I guess if two different mutexes would be used it would not be safe.

Comment: As long as every thread modifying `a` only does so with the mutex locked, it's safe.  It doesn't matter whether they do it through a pointer or directly.

Comment: And if the mutex is locked before **p** is used, then both **a** and **p** are protected? The conclusion being that every memory reference present in a section where a mutex is locked is protected, even if the memory is indirectly referenced ?

Comment: The mutex doesn't protect the code between the lock and unlock per se, it protects whatever is done between the time the lock happens and the time the unlock happens -- provided that those things are never touched, by any thread, without that same thread locking the mutex first.  Your threads wait for *the mutex*, not the object or a section of code... and if an object is only accessed when the mutex is held, then only one thread will access it at a time because only one thread can hold the mutex at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule when doing multithreading is that shared variables among threads that are read and written need to be accessed serially, which means that you must use some sort of synchronization primitive. Mutexes are a popular choice, but no matter what you end up using, you just need to remember that before reading from or writing to a shared variable, you need to acquire a lock to ensure consistency.

So, as long as every thread in your code agrees to always use the same lock before accessing a given variable, you're all good.

Now, to answer your specific questions:

> Is the code safe if, in the second thread, I lock a mutex before I
>   modify the value of `a` using the pointer variable?

It depends. How do you read `a` on the first thread? The first thread needs to lock the mutex too before accessing `a` in any way. If both threads lock the same mutex before reading or writing the value of `a`, then it is safe.

It's safe because the region of code between the mutex lock and unlock is exclusive (as long as every thread respects the rule that before doing `Y`, they need to acquire lock `X`), since only one thread at a time can have the lock.

As for this comment:

> And if the mutex is locked before p is used, then both a and p are
>   protected? The conclusion being that every memory reference present in
>   a section where a mutex is locked is protected, even if the memory is
>   indirectly referenced?

Mutexes don't protect memory regions or references, they protect a region of code. Whatever you make between locking and unlocking is exclusive; that's it. So, if every thread accessing or modifying either of `a` or `p` locks the same mutex before and unlocks afterwards, then *as a side-effect* you have synchronized accesses.

**TL;DR** Mutexes allow you to write code that never executes in parallel, you get to choose what that code does - a remarkably popular pattern is to access and modify shared variables.

Comment: @dragosb Think of a mutex as being the key to a room. Only one person is allowed inside the room at one time. To enter the room, you acquire the key. Once you are inside, what you do is your business and no one else can enter (and other people don't care about what you do, they just wait for their turn to enter). When you leave, you return the key and the next guy enters the room. So, essentially the mutex object is shared across all threads and you can use it however you want to synchronize them.

Comment: I have read before that mutexes protect regions of code...this confuses me a little. When you say that its code that never executes in parallel you mean that, when that critical section in one thread executes, all other threads of the process will not execute on other cores?

Comment: @dragosb All other threads that try to acquire the *same* lock object will have to wait and won't execute. But other threads that are doing other things where a lock isn't needed will of course keep executing.

Comment: hi  excellent answer @Filipe Gonçalves So, if a shared variable is going to be used by multiple threads (each thread with a different code maybe) a possible solution would be to define a "single way" to access that shared variable (a wrapper method maybe) and so all threads will acquire/release the same lock (all should use that wrapper method to access the shared variable), right? - Thanks